# Deploy Qt-project without QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

Is it possible to build Qt-project without QML ? For example, for building project without GUI we should use key `-no-gui` ? What about QML ? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your project only needs to depend on Qt modules that it actually needs.

In a QMake project file, for example. this is handled via the `QT` variable.

E.g. to use the QtNetwork module one would do this

```
QT += network
```

By default the `core` and `gui` modules are enabled, to remove the `gui` module do this

```
QT -= gui
```

The mechanism knows about module inter-dependencies, for example `qml` depends on `core` and `network` so

```
QT += qml
```

results in `core`, `gui`, `network` and `qml` being selected.

Since `qml` does not depend on `gui` that could still be removed

```
QT += qml
QT -= gui
```

resulting in `core`, `network` and `qml`

Obviously, if you where to select `qtquick`, then this would also imply `gui` as `qtquick` depends on `gui` and `qml`